# How to load records from a database in a dropdown using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
This is my edited HTML code... and i think ur right guys, there is a problem with my while T.T
```

This is my edited HTML code... and i think ur right guys, there is a problem with my while T.T
This is my edited HTML code... and i think ur right guys, there is a problem with my while T.T

This is my edited HTML code... and i think ur right guys, there is a problem with my while T.T

```
thankyou in advance..
```

This is my edited HTML code... and i think ur right guys, there is a problem with my while T.T

```
<body style="font-size:15px;font-family:sans-serif;padding:0px;margin:0px;">
<div style="min-width:300px;width:80%;margin:20px auto auto auto;border:1px 
solid black;padding:10px;">
<h1 style="font-size:30px;font-weight:bolder;font-family:arial">Contact 
Us</h1>


<form action="" method="post" id="ContactUs">
<h2 style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bolder;font-family:arial;margin- 
left:2%;">Personal Information</h2>
<input value="" placeholder="First Name" name="" style="display:block;min- 
width:280px;width:80%;padding:5px;height:30px;margin:10px auto 0% auto;">
<input value="" placeholder="Last Name" name="" style="display:block;min- 
width:280px;width:80%;padding:5px;height:30px;margin:10px auto 0% auto;">
<input value="" placeholder="Organization" name="" style="display:block;min- 
width:280px;width:80%;padding:5px;height:30px;margin:10px auto 0% auto;">
<input value="" placeholder="Email" name="" style="display:block;min- 
width:280px;width:80%;padding:5px;height:30px;margin:10px auto 0% auto;">
<input value="" placeholder="Phone Number" name="" style="display:block;min- 
width:280px;width:80%;padding:5px;height:30px;margin:10px auto 0% auto;">




<h2 style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bolder;font-family:arial;margin- 
left:2%;">Address</h2>
<?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
?>
<select id="ddlProvince" onchange="ShowHide()" name="province" 
style="display:block;min- 
width:280px;width:80%;padding:5px;height:30px;margin:10px auto 0% auto;">
<option value="0">---Select Province---</option>

<option value="<?php echo $row['province'];?>"><?php echo $row['province'];? 
></option>

</select>



<?php
    }
?>



</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is my php code before HTML tag.

Comment: <?php
    include("common/connect.php");

    $qry = "SELECT * FROM table_1 GROUP BY region ORDER BY region ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
?>

Comment: I want it as simple as possible THANK YOU!

Comment: So what is the issue with your code now? Except you are missing a `<?php } ?>`

Comment: all the provinces data is displaying on my page... But They are outside the dropdown menu..   I want them to be inside of the dropdown...

Comment: Please show the rendered HTML - your code looks correct

Comment: that is my HTML code.

Comment: It's PHP, not HTML - Open your browser. Click view-source!!!

Comment: There is no PHP code displayin on view source... im sorry i dont know what ur talking about im just a beginner here T.T

Comment: @mplungjan already written you whats the problem! You are missing a `<?php } ?>` after you output the option elements to close your while loop!

Comment: There is a reason why your options are not showing correctly. Open the URL to your page in a BROWSER. Then find the "view--source" or right-click and inspect. Then post the RENDERED HTML of the select code. If you really are missing the `<?php } ?>` after the `<option value="<?php echo $row['province'];?>"><?php echo $row['province'];?></option>` then you need to add it

Comment: And JFYI... beginners don't get any bonus here ;)

Comment: <select id="ddlProvince" onchange="ShowHide()" name="province" style="display:block;min-width:280px;width:80%;padding:5px;height:30px;margin:10px auto 0% auto;">
 <option value="0">---Select Province---</option>
     <option value="BASILAN">BASILAN</option>
   
</select>

Comment: I do have <?php } ?>  before the form end tag.

Comment: So please update the question with that tag BEFORE the `</select>`

Comment: You need it before `</select>`!

Comment: Your HTML works. So it could be CSS?Can you post the complete page?

Comment: There is a limit of 15 characters per comment.. how will i post it T.T

Comment: Just remove anything personal

Comment: done.. sorry i took a while

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna echo html you could go as follow:

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>   
    <option value="<?php echo $row['province']; ?>"><?php echo $row['province']; ?></option>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: I already did that.. it doesnt work.. because i have ajax, and i think its confusing for the code to read that

Answer (score 0):

Your while code should be

```html
<select id="ddlProvince" onchange="ShowHide()" name="province" 
style="display:block;min- 
width:280px;width:80%;padding:5px;height:30px;margin:10px auto 0% auto;">

<option value="0">---Select Province---</option>

<?php
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['province'];?>"><?php echo $row['province'];?></option>
<?php } ?>

</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be an error in your `while`, try it like this:

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){   
    echo "<option value='" . $row['province'] ."'>" . $row['province'] ."</option>";
}
?>
```

You where trying to write HTML outside the PHP `while`, i suspect that it was writing some wrong HTML, writing all the `option` outside the `select`

Comment: Thanks but same result T.T

Comment: It is valid to do `<?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  {   
    ?>   <option value="">.....</option>` but the loop MUST be closed with a `<?php } ?>`

Comment: Can you please show me what is the final rendered HTML in your webpage?

Comment: I have already asked for that twice in the comments under the question